# Can a beam splitter distinguish between more than two polarizations?

Tags: laser, polarization

*The following is based on a very basic understanding of lasers, that
  may be approximate or altogether completely erroneous.*

Given a (single-mode) laser beam, a [beam-splitting polarizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer#Beam-splitting_polarizers) distinguishes between two orthogonal polarizations that correspond to the optic axis of the birefringent material.  If the beam is s-polarized, it passes through, and if it is p-polarized, it is sent at an angle.  In the other cases, that is, with different polarizations, it is absorbed (*is that correct?*).

**Question:**  Does there exist a material/device that takes a laser beam as input, and sends it at an angle based on its polarization?  I know beforehand that the polarization is, e.g., a multiple of $\pi/6$.

**Question (graphically):**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "sends it at an angle based on its polarization"? Perhaps you're asking about [Polarization rotators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_rotator) or [wave plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveplate#Half-wave_plate)?

Comment: I see the beam-splitting polarizer as doing the following: if the input beam has a polarization $\theta$, then send it at angle $0$; if the input beam has a polarization of $\theta\pm \pi$, then send it at angle $90$; otherwise, absorb.  Provided that this is a correct interpretation, I'm looking for a device that would do it with $k$ polarizations $\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_k$, sending beams with polarization $\theta_i$ at an angle of $(i-1)\times 2\pi/k$, for instance.  Am I being any clearer?

Comment: Do you mean you have 6 linear components at $\pi/6$ from each other? Are they from the same laser, are they coherent?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand precisely your question—my bad for sure.  My setting, so far, is that I have a laser, with polarization say $0$ degrees, and its beam has seen its polarization changed through several rotations of $\pi/6$.  My goal now is for instance to implement the following: if its polarization is $0$ or $\pi/2$, then rotate the polarization by $\pi/2$, otherwise leave it untouched.  One possible way to do so is if I can "branch" it to a different location in space depending on polarization: this is precisely what I ask above.  Does this make any sense?

Comment: is the spatial separation of the different outputs really necessary? do you really want N different paths in the output of this device? or can it be ok to have a single path in output, of which you know/measure the exact direction of the polarization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the beam is s-polarized, it passes through, and if it is p-polarized, it is sent at an angle.

This is correct

> In the other cases, that is, with different polarizations, it is absorbed (is that correct?).

This is not correct. No matter the polarization state of the input (linear, elliptical, tilted..) the beam splitter will split the two linear orthogonal components of the input, which are parallel and perpendicular to the beam splitter axis. These two components are the projections of the input polarization state on orthogonal directions (a base) dictated by the orientation of the beam splitter. The sum of the two output intensities is always equal to the input intensity. For example, if the input is linear at 45 deg after the beam splitter you'll have two beams with identical intensity, one polarized linear vertical, the other linear horizontal.

EDIT:
[image: polarization device]
If I understand you'd like to have for the polarization what a grating is for the wavelength. I cannot find a *passive* material that can send to different outputs arbitrary input polarizations (it doesn't mean there is none). So I thought about the following *active* system (it should work but is quite complicated to do practically):

You analyze the polarization state and based on the result you actively and automatically do something, like changing the beam direction, if really needed. What you have to do is to measure the **[Stokes parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_parameters)** of the input on the fly, and based on that you can steer the beam. In the picture: $X,Y$ are $s$ and $p$ components; $a,b$ are linear components rotated by 45°. Every letter corresponds to an intensity ($|E|^2$).
As you know that the input is linear, you need to find only its orientation $\theta=1/2  \arctan(U/Q)$, where $Q=X-Y$ and $U=a-b$

I'm curious to see if a passive solution exists.

Comment: Thanks!  Should I gather from this that there is no way to do what I want?

Comment: I edited the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I won't leave the question open for a passive solution, but if anyone has some input, feel free to chime in!

Answer (score 2):

The polarizing beam splitter responds to the electric field of the light; the polarization state is defined by the orientation of the electric field with respect to the plane of incidence of a ray of light; if the electric field is parallel to the plane of incidence it is called P polarized; if it is at right angles, sideways, it is called S polarized; these are the first letters of corresponding German words.

If the electric field is neither S nor P then it is composed of both; there is an S component, and a P component; their vector sum is the electric field.

When only naturally occurring materials were used to make polarizing beam splitters, the separation angles were determined by the crystal structure.  Today the beamsplitter is typically engineered to provide orthogonal beams.  You could use a chain of orthogonal beamsplitters to accomplish a division of the original beam into 6 or more parts, with the angles of your choosing.

The easiest way to proceed is to use a combination of polarizing beam splitters (PBS) and half-wave plates (HWP) that are calibrated for the laser wavelength of the beam. Split the beam, insert a HWP in each output beam, set to rotate the plane of polarization; now insert a PBS in each of these beams: this gives four distinct polarization angles.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of the two first paragraphs!  I did not understand the last one, though, I'm sorry.  Are you saying that what I want is possible, or not?

Comment: The first beamspltter divides the beam into two orthogonal beams. If you place a beam spltter in both of these beams, oriented the same as the first wrt each beam, you will just get one beam from each of the beamsplitters. But if you orient the beamsplitter differently, it will divide each beam again, so now you have four distinct polarized beams, with different angles. The beamsplitters could be mounted in rotation mounts; it could get messy.

Comment: Thanks!  I *think* this is precisely the part I get; but it does not seem to imply the nonexistence of the device pictured in the question.  Let me rephrase it again.  Let a beam splitter have "orientation" $\theta$, meaning that it lets $\theta$-polarized beams through, and $(\theta+\pi/2)$-polarized beams are reflected at $90$ degrees.  Is it possible to have a beam splitter such that $\theta$-polarized beams go through, $\theta+\pi/4$-polarized beams go at a $45$° angle, $\theta + 2\pi/4$-polarized beams at a $90$° angle, and $\theta+3\pi/4$-polarized beams at a $135$° angle?  Thanks a lot!